# Derivative of $x^2$ and differences between differences of squares (On a fact mentioned by G. Strang)

Tags: calculus

In a book on Calculus (I think it was Strang's) the author mentioned the following fact, with on the first line the squares, on the second the first differences, and on the third the differences of the differences

$\begin{array}
{}1 & & 4 & & 9 & & 16 & & 25 & & 36 & & \dots  \\
 & 3 & & 5 & & 7 & & 9 & & 11 & & \dots \\
 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & &  2 & & \dots
\end{array}$

In the third line (difference of the difference) we always get $2$ and,  precisely, $2x$ is the derivative of $x^2$.

(I ask the question since I did not really understand Strang's explanation, though Strang is a great teacher.)

Questions
(1) Are there other examples of this phenomenon?
(2) What is the link, if there is any, between "differences of differences of squares" and the derivative of $x^2$?

Comment: The squares are $a_n = n^2$. The first differences are $a_n - a_{n-1} = n^2 - (n-1)^2 = 2n - 1$. The second differences are thus $2n-1 - (2(n-1)-1) = 2$ (constant). In general, you can actually show that $a_n$ is a degree $d$ polynomial in $n$ if and only if the $d$-th difference is constant (and no earlier difference is constant). You can also show that if $d\in\Bbb{N}$ and $a_n = n^d$, then the $d$-th difference of this sequence is $d!$ ($d$ factorial). In the continuous case, the $d$-th derivative of $x^d$ is $d!$ (e.g. second derivative of $x^2$ is $2!$).

Comment: @MinusOneTwelth. Thanks for this precise answer.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth You should write that up as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The squares are $a_n=n^2$. The first differences are $$a_n−a_{n−1}=n^2−(n−1)^2=2n−1.$$ The second differences are thus $2n−1−(2(n−1)−1)=2$ (constant). In general, you can actually show that $a_n$ is a degree $d$ polynomial in $n$ if and only if the $d$-th difference is constant (and no earlier difference is constant). You can also show that if $d∈\Bbb{N}$ and $a_n=n^d$, then the $d$-th difference of this sequence is $d!$ ($d$ factorial). In the continuous case, the $d$-th derivative of $x^d$ is $d!$ (e.g. second derivative of $x^2$ is $2!$).